# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.router'

Tags: django-rest-framework

Hi I'm getting this error please help me. I'm new on this field and I'm getting this error. I tried to fix it myself in the following ways: I have the latest version of packages, But I still tried to update everything `django`, `djangorestframework`, etc. But this error does not go away. I really do not know what to do, trying to solve this problem for more than a day. I checked the documentation but didn't find anything there that could lead to the problem I have (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.router'`)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 443, in execute
    self.check()
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 475, in check
    all_issues = checks.run_checks(
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 88, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs, databases=databases)
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 494, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 715, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 708, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/server/urls.py", line 7, in <module>
    path('', include('product.urls')),
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 38, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
    File "/home/henadzi/project/onlineshop/product/urls.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rest_framework.router import DefaultRouter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rest_framework.router'
```

My `urls.py`:

```py
from django.urls import include, path
from product.views import ProductViewSet
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.router import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('', ProductViewSet, basename="ProductViewSet")


urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

My `INSTALLED_APPS` is:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'product',
]
```

[image]

Comment: You import the wrong path
`from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter` not `from rest_framework.router import DefaultRouter`

Answer (score 0):

You have extra and wrong imports in your `urls.py` module:

```py
from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework.router import DefaultRouter
```

But you just only need this import:

```py
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
```

After this change this error will go away and you can run your project successfully.